# Simplifying an xpath expression used by selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium

I've got the following XPath expression that I call from selenium (technically, from splinter, which is calling selenium):

```
//label[text()="data"]/following-sibling::div/input|//label[text()="data"]/following-sibling::div/textarea
```

Is there a way to simplify this expression? The following doesn't work in selenium, although it seems to work in [AquaPath](http://ditchnet.org/aquapath/):

```
//label[text()="data"]/following-sibling::div/(input|textarea)
```

Comment: Could you plx show us your html code?

Comment: Lorin, Was my answer useful to you, or do you still have any problems? I just made an update, showing how to write a compact expression when there are significant number of alternatives.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, it was useful. In my case, I have only two alternatives, so the initial solution works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try**:

```
//label[text()="data"]/following-sibling::div/*[self::input or self::textarea]
```

**Whenever there are many (more than 3 alternatives), an expression like this is considerably shorter:**

```
someExpr/*[contains('|name1|name2|name3|name4|', concat('|',name(), '|'))]
```